# Sort column data as per pre defined order using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a vector:

```
cat_order <- c('apple', 'banana', 'orange')
```

and my `dataframe`:

```
fruitDF

fruits    price
apple     2.2
orange    1.7
banana    1.5
banana    1.2
orange    3.2
apple     2.1
orange    1.1
banana    4.1
```

**What do I want?**

```
fruits    price
apple     2.2
banana    1.5
orange    1.7
banana    1.2
orange    3.2
apple     2.1
banana    4.1
orange    1.1
```

**What did I do?**

I could order by price

```
fruitDF[order(price),]
```

but that is because it is `quantitative` but I want to sort the `fruitDF` as per the categorical `cat_order`, how do I do?

Comment: Your new expected is not clear.  For the first 3 rows, it follows the order of cat_order, then 4th row is 'banana' can you please explain

Comment: The issue with your ordering is that the 'apple' absent in one of the levels, it can be taken as 2nd or 3rd because the column is already not in order.  If we can clear that part, it would be more easier

Answer (score 2):

We can convert the 'fruits' column to `factor` with `levels` specified in `order`

```
fruitDF[order(factor(fruitDF$fruits, levels = cat_order)),]
#    fruits price
#2  apple   2.2
#1 banana   1.5
#3 orange   1.7
```

Or another option is `match`

```
fruitDF[match(fruitDF$fruits, cat_order),]
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(fruitDF)[order(match(fruits, order))]
```

#### data

```
fruitDF <- structure(list(fruits = c("banana", "apple", "orange"), price = c(1.5, 
2.2, 1.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: this actually does not work for the missing value. I updated the`DF`, could you please check?

Comment: @floss you said missing value, i don't see any missing value in the new data updated

Comment: By missing values, I mean the values are not repeated one after another. For eg: `apple` `orange` .. here `banana` is missing. So even though the values are missing, it has to follow the order, `apple` `banana` `orange`. If the value does not exist, use the next value in order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pursue a `tidyverse` solution, you can do the following (data frame from @akrun):

```
library(dplyr)

fruitDF %>%
  arrange(match(fruits, cat_order))
```

Or:

```
fruitDF %>%
  arrange(factor(fruits, levels = cat_order))
```